# redirect based on directory and subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

ok so it is not as simple as the title suggests. What I want to do is take what a person enters as the url say www.mysite.com/region --- I want to direct the person to a php page located in subfolder/companyx/region.php ... and that may bit easier but I also have subdomains.

I have the subdomains figured out where if a person inputs companyx.mysite.com it includes:

```
<?php
    $sub = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
    if ($sub == 'mysite') {
        include 'home.php';
    } else if ($sub == 'www') {
        include 'home.php';
    }
    else {
        include 'subfolder/'.basename($sub).'.php';
    }
?>
```

the problem i am having is how do i direct both the subdomain and the /region accordingly?

the region is stored /subfolder/companyx/region.php and the sub domain is stored in /subfolder/companyx.php

i've tried to make the companyx.php file something like this:

```
$end = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($end != '') {
    include 'companyx/region.php';
} else {
    include 'companyx/index.php';
}
?>
```

this could be way off but i dont really want to use rewrite rules as i will have many regions and many companies and do not want a lot of rules...

Comment: htaccess is the right solution for this

Comment: @sanjeev how would i write it so that it so that say someone entered companyx.mysite.com/north would goto one php file and companyy.mysite.com/north would go to another